# Creating Google accounts through API forcing users to verify sign in city

Tags: php, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Using Google's Directory API to create users, I'm now running into an issue where the user is asked what city they usually sign in from.

This is a problem because the webserver used to create the account via the API is in a different location than the users are logging in from for the first time. This hasn't happened before and it's suddenly happening now (no code change).

Has anyone ran into this, and is there a way to mitigate it?

For the record, I'm using a PHP implementation, if it matters.

*Edit: Clarification that the webserver in another location is the webserver used to create the Google account via the API.*

Answer (score 0):

See Google's [FAQ on suspicious logins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6002699?hl=en). I'd recommend setting a strong initial password for these users that is 8+ characters in length and contains upper and lowercase as well as numbers or punctuation.

Comment: Thanks, but the FAQs don't provide a way around my issue. The challenge is being presented due to a location difference between where the account was created and where the user is now trying to log in for the first time.

The domain in question is a K-12 edu domain.

Comment: Are you setting strong passwords?

Comment: It's a randomly generated 8 character alpha numeric password. Being that young students in elementary school are using this, I can't give them a 16 character password with symbols; I'd have just as many support calls from parents not being able to copy and paste. I'm going to do some tests to see if I can always replicate the issue, and see if a more complex password works. I'll report back if I can replicate. Thanks, Jay. (Problem not confirmed solved yet, though).

Comment: Created user with password of 123 (allowed via API). It didn't prompt me for location verification. So this seems random. I'll likely have to try to send an email to Google Support and hope that leads me to something. Thanks for the suggestion.